# ElasticSearch: is it possible to query with geo spatial biasing?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to query documents with biasing according to distance from a geo_point, 
currently I'm using the geo_distance filter which filters all documents with larger distance,
but I want some sort of biasing.

for example, If I'm querying for 10 documents and only 6 falls inside the geo_distance filter, return also 4 documents that have a larger distance.

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your main query into [Custom Filters Score Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query.html) and put your geo_distance filter as one of the filters.